# Show sql query result Asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem with SQL, I really don't know what it is wrong. I am doing similiar web page like phpmyadmin but in asp.net. The problem is with getting the query result. I have a TextBox in which you can put your sql code and after button click the code is executed. All that works fine, but i would also like to see resutls of some codes especially with SELECT. I have tried one code but it doesn't seem to work. Please help.

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection con = povezava)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = tb_koda.Text;
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            dt.Load(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This is the code i wrote but nothing is returnded as a result.

Comment: Well, at this point you may have saved the data in the DataTable object, now you just need to do something with it (it won't be displayed in the page unless you do something with it)

Comment: when you step thru the code and use the `Data Visualizer` do you see any rows of data filled..? if so then if you're expecting to see the data in a DataGrid.. then you need to bind the datagrid to the dt and call the DataBind method of the DataGridView.. please explain how you are expecting to see this data..also allowing users to pass query's to a Database via a Textbox is not a good thing.. are you familiar with `SQL Injection` as well as SQL Servers Special Characters in regards to a query not executing..??

Comment: Yes in fact i used this, but no data was filled that is what is bothering me.

Comment: You might want to look up sql injection...this approach is wide open. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTable` is an in-memory object; it doesn't relate to anything on the screen. You need to extract the contents of the `DataTable` into the `TextBox`, although binding it to, for example, a `GridView` might produce friendlier results.

Do take heed of the SQL injection advice too!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
using (SqlConnection con = povezava) 
{
using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand()) 
{
    command.CommandText = tb_koda.Text;
    command.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command)) 
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        yourDataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        yourDataGrid.DataBind();
    }
    con.Close();
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection con = povezava) {
    using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = tb_koda.Text;
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command)) 
            adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```